# Is the word "amiss "one of the synonyms for "sick"?

Tags: word-meaning, synonyms

thesaurus.com claims one of the synonyms for the word "amiss" is "sick", even though I could not find such a definition in other dictionaries. Also, this is a context from a book in which the word "sick" would fit nicely as they are speaking of a person in such a state.

..to-day he’s not at all amiss—a considerable change
since the afternoon.

Comment: Your Dostoyevsky translation is nearly 110 years old. Amiss, meaning 'not right' or 'out of order' was more common then. The hyphenation of 'to-day' is another clue about the age of the text.

Comment: Yes, I know that but why would there be this synonym included in a modern thesaurus (https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/amiss)?

Comment: Thesauruses include words that are old fashioned or rarely used.